# Quality differences of graphics produces by PC and Mac in R

Tags: r, plot

Not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this question, so please feel free to delete it...

I've been preparing a little introduction to course lately, and in the section about saving plots I noticed something odd. When I created a figure on my work PC, it looked the way it should. But when I ran the exact same code again on my Mac at home, the image looked somewhat blurred. I tried this for the png, tiff, and jpeg formats, the result is the same, the plot looks nicer when produced on a PC. I include two graphs below so you can see for yourself. (The first the the PC plot, the second the Mac plot). Although the PC produces the better quality, the figure produced by the Mac is larger (19 vs 8 KB). Below is another image, where both figures are magnified (Mac left, PC right). While the PC draws a crisp line, the Mac produces some kind of a shading around the lines. Can anyone explain why this is the case and how I can produce better quality plots on the Mac? I played around with the options, in particular the `type` argument, but couldn't neither find a solution, nor find help on the internet.

Here is the code to generate the plot:

```
set.seed(2)
BMI<-rnorm(n=1000, m=24.2, sd=2.2) 
png(file="fig3_m2.png", width=700, height=700, res=120)
par(mgp=c(1.7,.6,0), mar=c(3,3,2,2), yaxs="i")
x <- hist(BMI, freq=F, main="Distribution of BMI",
          xlab="Body Mass Index", col="lightgreen",
          ylim=c(0,.2), 
          breaks=seq(min(BMI), max(BMI), length=18))
box()
dev.off()
```

[image: PC plot] [image: Plot mac]  [image: Close up comparison Mac vs. PC]

Comment: On Mac OS, try `png(..., antialias="none")`. That should give you results more similar to the Windows version. It will never be exactly the same because different OSs use different underlying software ('graphics devices') to render the output.

Comment: @bdemarest: post as answer?